# Cannot get the span text using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a supplier with login web page in which I try to get the price and availability. While in VBA the selectors are working in Python I get None.

This is the HTML part from which I get the price:

```html
<div class="product-info-price">
  <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product- 
  id="32686" data-price-box="product-id-32686">
    <span class="special-price">
      <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"  itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span class="price-label">Ειδική Τιμή</span>
        <span  id="product-price-32686"  data-price-amount="7.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper " >
          <span class="price">7,90 €</span>
        </span>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="7.9" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In VBA, I use the following selector:

```
.price-box .price-final_price .price
```

In Python I use:

```
price = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'price'})

if price is not None:
  price_text = price.text.strip()
  print(price_text)
else:
  price_text = "0,00"
  print(price_text)
```

and I get always `0,00` as price..

What should I change in `soup.find`?

Comment: its only a part of..

Comment: Can you try it again with `if price` instead of `if price is not None`?

Comment: The same result, Do I have to get the div and then the span, I cannot get directly the span?

Comment: It looks like you need to remove the space between the two class selector tags, since they are on the same element: `.price-box.price-final_price .price` Since the `price-final_price` class appears at multiple levels, try using a different selector class.

Comment: So I do  price = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'price-box.price-final_price .price'})

Comment: I just tested this and I get the price from your example.

Comment: This code works as expected. How do You get this `html`?

Answer (score 3):

Css selectors are generally faster than xpath. You can use the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="product-info-price">
  <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product- 
  id="32686" data-price-box="product-id-32686">
    <span class="special-price">
      <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"  itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span class="price-label">Ειδική Τιμή</span>
        <span  id="product-price-32686"  data-price-amount="7.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper " >
          <span class="price">7,90 €</span>
        </span>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="7.9" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
prices = [price.text for price in soup.select('.price')]
print(prices)
```

Alternatively:

```
altPrices = [price['content'] for price in soup.select("[itemprop=price]")]
print(altPrices)
```

Comment: I didn't know that you could extract the metadata that way.  I will definitely use this technique in the future.

Comment: @QHarr can you explain me a bit more the prices = [price.text for price in soup.select('.price')] what is does?

Comment: It’s a list comprehension which extracts the text of each matching element returned

Comment: @QHarr I place it in the middle of ... price = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'price'}) 

altPrices = [price['content'] for price in soup.select("[itemprop=price]")]
print(altPrices)

if price is not None:

I get only the URLs to be processed, its like is not logged in.. I logged in using chromedriver

Comment: @QHarr I get empty list

Comment: can you provide the url?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer lxml, it's clear for me to use xPath instead of css selectors:

```
from lxml import html
all_html = html.fromstring(the_entire_html)
price = all_html.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content')
# or
price = all_html.xpath('//div[@class="product-info-price"]//span[@class="price"]/text()')
```